# Algorithm for calculating the toughness of a graph

Tags: graphs

Let $G$ be a graph. **Toughness** is defined as
$$
t(G)=\min _S \frac{|S|}{c(G-S)}
$$
where $c$ is the number of connected components and the minimum is taken over all vertex cuts $S$ of $G$ (Graph toughness was first introduced by Václav Chvátal (1973)).

A graph is $l$-tough if $t(G)\ge l$. Testing whether a graph is q-tough is co-NP-complete (Bauer, Hakimi & Schmeichel 1990).

Apart from the definition, I am unsure if there are any equivalent algorithms for calculating the toughness of a graph. The first challenge I encountered was **traversing all the cut sets** (or traversing all non-empty proper subsets of the vertex set). However, it seems that the cost of traversing all non-empty proper subsets is still significant.

For example, I'd like to determine the toughness of the following graph.

[image]

Its adjacency list is as follows:

```
{{1, 2, 3, 9, 14, 15, 16, 18}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 13}, {0, 1, 3, 
  4, 5, 7, 8, 14}, {0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 
  17}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7}, {2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 
  5}, {2, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 10, 12, 13}, {1, 3, 9, 11, 12, 13}, {1, 3, 
  10}, {3, 9, 10}, {1, 9, 10}, {0, 2, 3, 15, 18, 17}, {0, 3, 14, 16, 
  18, 17}, {0, 3, 15}, {0, 14, 15}, {3, 14, 15}}
```